# Install single package from Rawhide

Tags: fedora, yum, dnf

How can one install a single Rawhide package, without upgrading the entire
operating system?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
yum install fedora-repos-rawhide
yum install --enablerepo rawhide bash
```

Comment: Any info on how to do this with RPMFusion's rawhide repo?

Comment: Same with dnf.  To upgrade an existing package, add `--best --allowerasing` (it tells you if you need).

Answer (score 24):

This is the top search result for this inquiry. Key signing has changed for F27 on, so to pull a package from rawhide use the following:

```
sudo dnf install fedora-repos-rawhide -y
sudo dnf --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=rawhide --releasever=[next release #, e.g. if you're on 27 use 28] install [package name]
```

You can also import the key manually from the Fedora website or force an unauthenticated upgrade to the newest fedora-repos.

Comment: If you already have the package installed and you want to pull in a _newer_ version from Rawhide, you need `upgrade`, not `install`, but this is otherwise correct.

Comment: It seems `--releasever=[n+1]` is presently critical to avoid "Import of key(s) didn't help, wrong key(s)?" error (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1473241, https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1456079).  Except that didn't work for me either.