# How can I install a development package (rawhide) on Fedora 23

Tags: package, fedora, yum, armadillo, fedora-23

I am trying to install the lattest `armadillo` version. From the [package list](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/armadillo-devel) I can see `rawhide 7.100.3-2.fc25`.

I run `Fedora 23` and cannot manage to install this package directly.
So following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968410/install-single-package-from-rawhide/24968411#24968411)I did

```
dnf install fedora-repos-rawhide
dnf install --enablerepo rawhide armadillo
```

I get:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 1:16:40 ago on Tue May 31 18:20:30 2016.
Package armadillo-6.700.6-1.fc23.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
```

How can I install `using dnf` the proper package ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `update`, since your package is already installed:

```
dnf update --enablerepo rawhide armadillo
```

Comment: This does not seem to be working, the proposed version is `6.700.6-1.fc25`

Comment: The latest version was build today, so it is not available in mirrors, or you have cached information in your computer. Try to wait, `dnf clean metadata` to refresh data or download the package directly from [koji](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=769565)

Comment: I tried to get the .rpm already but it cannot be installed due to dependencies

Comment: If the dependencies are already in rawhide repository, you can install the with the downloaded package using `dnf update --enablerepo rawhide path-to.rpm`. But note that it is not recommended to mix packages from different release versions.